# with -lpthread, g++ compiler error, "undefined reference to " semaphore calls such as `sem_open'

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, system-calls, undefined-reference

I am new to posix thread library, and I tried to compile a sample code from a tutorial with:

```
g++ -lpthread agreement.cpp -o agreement
```

however I was not able to compile the code and got the following error message:

```
a3q2.cpp:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `sem_open'
a3q2.cpp:(.text+0xab): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
a3q2.cpp:(.text+0x290): undefined reference to `sem_post'
a3q2.cpp:(.text+0x2af): undefined reference to `sem_close'
a3q2.cpp:(.text+0x2bb): undefined reference to `sem_unlink'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [a3q2_exe] Error 1
```

I am aware that -lpthread is needed for compilation to work, but is there any other options i might need to solve the problem? if not how do I have to install the "proper" pthread library?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want `-pthread`, not `-lpthread`. Compiling with pthreads support may require more than just a library. Your platform may require `-lrt` for semaphores (did you check the man page?).

Comment: Undefined reference is **linker**, not **compiler** error.

Comment: Also, objects (and archives) providing symbols must be ordered *after* objects using those symbols when linking.  It may not matter here, but get into the habit of putting `-lfoo` towards the *end* of the command, not the *start*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want the compile option `-pthread` (if you are really using pthreads).  If you just need those functions they are in `librt` so use `-lrt`

Comment: thanks a ton, i was able to solve the problem with `-pthread` but
could you elaborate on why that is? and whats the difference between `-lpthread` and `-pthread`? Thanks

Comment: @Mike: If you look at the manpage for gcc, -pthread: "Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker." The exact flags may differ from platform to platform; on your system, it may be something like "-D__PTHREADS -lpthread -lrt", which means that just passing "-lpthread" isn't sufficient. You could figure out exactly what it maps to on every platform you care about and pass that instead, by why?

Comment: @Mike: On top of that, some other compilers (I believe icc) in "gcc compatibility mode" may also use -pthread to influence some code generation and/or optimization decisions, so if you end-run around it, you could end up with code that compiles and links but crashes 1 in a million times…