# semaphore implementation

Tags: c, semaphore

I am getting error in the following program. I want to demonstrate how two processes can share a variable using semaphore. Can anyone guide me?

I am not able to debug the errors...

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/sem.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
int main()
{
  int pid,mutex=1;
  int semid;               /* semid of semaphore set */
  key_t key = 1234; /* key to pass to semget() */
  int nsems = 1; /* nsems to pass to semget() */
  semid=semget(key,nsems,IPC_CREAT|0666);
  if (semid<0) 
  { 
    perror("Semaphore creation failed ");
  }
  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) 
  {
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
  }
  else if(pid==0)
  {
    sem_wait(&semid);
    printf("IN CHILD PROCESS :\n");
    mutex++; 
    printf("value of shared variable =%d",mutex);
    sem_post(&semid);
    return 0;
  }
  sem_wait(&semid);
  printf("IN PARENT PROCESS :\n");
  mutex--;
  printf("value of shared variable =%d",mutex);
  sem_post(&semid);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: please edit your question to contain the error

Comment: i dont hav linux at home...... this is the program which i tried to implement in college......i dont knw the exact errors... it was related to semid....

Comment: The flag is IPC_CREAT not IPC_CREATE , please edit the code and include the definitions for shm_wait() and shm_post()

Comment: thanks.... but what is shm_wait() and shm_post()???

Comment: ok... but sem_wait and sem_post are predefined functions which is defined in semaphore.h headerfile..... so why there is a need to define them again ???

Comment: no you don't have to , but you must compile with option -pthread , for them to work , see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111291/with-lpthread-g-compiler-error-undefined-reference-to-semaphore-calls-su for more details

Comment: did you get the answer for this?

Answer (score 26):

Your Fundamentals are wrong, the program won't work, so go through the basics and rewrite the program.

Some of the corrections you must make are:

1) You must make a variable of semaphore type

```
sem_t semvar;
```

2) The functions `sem_wait()`, `sem_post()` require the semaphore variable but you are passing the semaphore id, which makes no sense.

```
sem_wait(&semvar);
   //your critical section code
sem_post(&semvar);
```

3) You are passing the semaphore to `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()`  without initializing it. You must initialize it to 1 (in your case) before using it, or you will have a deadlock.

```
ret = semctl( semid, 1, SETVAL, sem);
if (ret == 1)
     perror("Semaphore failed to initialize");
```

Study the semaphore API's from the man page and go through this [example](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Classes/537/Fall2008/Notes/threads-semaphores.txt).

Comment: i hav a doubt..... if im creating a semaphore variable using sem_t then how we can get the semid of that variable ??? is there any need of using semid in my program ????   even after reading the man page , im confused

Comment: you get semid using semgets() function , there is all the need for semid , for example in the above code ,you can use the semid in semctl()

Comment: (sem_wait, sem_post) should not go together with semctl because they are not compatible. I just wrote an answer about this

Comment: More importantly, why does everyone keep saying "man page" instead of "main page."

Ordinarily, I'd say it's a typo but even on the "main page" it says "man page". (See: [FIGURE: INITIALIZING A SEMAPHORE])

Comment: what you have answered its correct in approach, but the question is about IPC with semaphores implementation & your answer is about a critical section problem sem_wait & sem_post.

Answer (score 18):

The fundamental issue with your code is that you mix two APIs. Unfortunately online resources are not great at pointing this out, but there are two semaphore APIs on UNIX-like systems:

- POSIX IPC API, which is a standard API
- System V API, which is coming from the old Unix world, but practically available almost all Unix systems

Looking at the code above you used semget() from the System V API and tried to post through sem_post() which comes from the POSIX API. It is not possible to mix them.

To decide which semaphore API you want you don't have so many great resources. The simple best is the "Unix Network Programming" by Stevens. The section that you probably interested in is in Vol #2.

These two APIs are surprisingly different. Both support the textbook style semaphores but there are a few good and bad points in the System V API worth mentioning:

- it builds on semaphore sets, so once you created an object with semget() that is a set of semaphores rather then a single one
- the System V API allows you to do atomic operations on these sets. so you can modify or wait for multiple semaphores in a set
- the SysV API allows you to wait for a semaphore to reach a threshold rather than only being non-zero. waiting for a non-zero threshold is also supported, but my previous sentence implies that
- the semaphore resources are pretty limited on every unixes. you can check these with the 'ipcs' command
- there is an undo feature of the System V semaphores, so you can make sure that abnormal program termination doesn't leave your semaphores in an undesired state

Answer (score 4):

Vary the consumer-rate and the producer-rate (using sleep), to better understand the operation of code. The code below is the consumer-producer simulation (over a max-limit on container).

**Code for your reference:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t semP, semC;
int stock_count = 0;
const int stock_max_limit=5;

void *producer(void *arg) {
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        while(stock_max_limit == stock_count){
            printf("stock overflow, production on wait..\n");
            sem_wait(&semC);
            printf("production operation continues..\n");
        }

        sleep(1);   //production decided here
        stock_count++;
        printf("P::stock-count : %d\n",stock_count);
        sem_post(&semP);
        printf("P::post signal..\n");
    }
 }

void *consumer(void *arg) {
    int i, sum=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        while(0 == stock_count){
            printf("stock empty, consumer on wait..\n");
            sem_wait(&semP);
            printf("consumer operation continues..\n");
        }

        sleep(2);   //consumer rate decided here
        stock_count--;
        printf("C::stock-count : %d\n", stock_count);
        sem_post(&semC);
        printf("C::post signal..\n");
        }
}

int main(void) {

    pthread_t tid0,tid1;
    sem_init(&semP, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&semC, 0, 0);

        pthread_create(&tid0, NULL, consumer, NULL);
        pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, producer, NULL);
        pthread_join(tid0, NULL);
        pthread_join(tid1, NULL);

    sem_destroy(&semC);
    sem_destroy(&semP);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please check this out below sample code for semaphore implementation(Lock and unlock).

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    #include <sys/sem.h>
    int main()
    {
            int key,share_id,num;
            char *data;
            int semid;
            struct sembuf sb={0,-1,0};
            key=ftok(".",'a');
            if(key == -1 ) {
                    printf("\n\n Initialization Falied of shared memory \n\n");
                    return 1;
            }
            share_id=shmget(key,1024,IPC_CREAT|0744);
            if(share_id == -1 ) {
                    printf("\n\n Error captured while share memory allocation\n\n");
                    return 1;
            }
            data=(char *)shmat(share_id,(void *)0,0);
            strcpy(data,"Testing string\n");
            if(!fork()) { //Child Porcess
                 sb.sem_op=-1; //Lock
                 semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);

                 strncat(data,"feeding form child\n",20);

                 sb.sem_op=1;//Unlock
                 semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);
                 _Exit(0);
            } else {     //Parent Process
              sb.sem_op=-1; //Lock
              semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);

               strncat(data,"feeding form parent\n",20);

              sb.sem_op=1;//Unlock
              semop(share_id,(struct sembuf *)&sb,1);

            }
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Gyan OK...this is new..How does passing shared memory id to a semaphore api which accepts a sem id work here ??

Comment: indeed, I guess there is a typo in the code: shm versus sem