# C programs synchronization

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to use POSIX in windows and use semaphores for synchronization of C and C++ programs.Since we are talking for separate programs, is this even possible? Or semaphores are only for sync in C/C++ files of the same program?

Comment: I'd try to use a library, like boost to help figure out Shared mem and locks with Windows. Check out this - they discuss some of what I think you are looking for http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory.windows_shared_memory

Comment: in linux (and I suspect windows) a 'named semaphore' (the kind used to communicate between separate processes) is actually a file under the /proc file system.   A 'named semnaphore' works very well for syncronization between different executables.

Answer (score 1):

For communication between different programs, you need to use **named semaphores**.
In POSIX Threads, the correct method to acquire a semaphore is : sem_open
Just give a name to the semaphore, and use the same name in the programs which need to communicate.

See this answer for more details on how to do it:
[How to share semaphores between processes using shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory)

Comment: isn't sem_wait and sem_post like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182328/?

Comment: you use sem_open to create or open a shared semaphore. Then you use sem_post and sem_wait to use the semaphore (release and acquire respectively).

Comment: yes I know this applies in the case of POSIX but since I can only use the WIndows semaphores what are the equivalent commands in Windows for sem_wait and sem_post?

Comment: you have 2 solutions: either you use pthreads (POSIX Threads) in Win32, or you use the Win32 API. In the 1st case, you can use the mingw w64 compiler suite, and then use sem_open, sem_post, sem_wait, sem_close. In the 2nd case, you can use the following methods : CreateSemaphore/CreateSemaphoreEx/OpenSemaphore/ReleaseSemaphore/WairForSingleObject/WaitFor... Since you stated you wanted to use POSIX, the 1st solution seems natural.

Comment: actually I have to sync two processes and specifically the for loop of the first process with the for loop of the second process so how the code will look like with the Windows commands you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Semaphores are members in Inter Process Communication tools. They can natively be used in C or C++ to synchronize different programs.

Answer (score 0):

For synchronization between seperate processes, a semaphore needs to be used.

See the following:
[Semaphores](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/semaphore.h.html)